# Authorization Header - IBM Cloud Object Storage

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage

I am following the Cloud Object Storage documentation: https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/manage-access#authentication in the Manage Access part, I tried in several ways and I can not generate a authorization header that works in my GET and POST requests, I would like to know if there is any possibility of someone helping me to generate this Authorization string that actually works on REST API requests, as I can not. thanks

Comment: Consider adding some code, what have you already tried and what is the specific error that you are facing

Comment: I am making requests through a low-code platform and a 403 error is returned